# Dynamic port mapping makes my task unavailable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have basic ecs configuration with cluster EC2 Linux + Networking with 1 EC2 Instance.

Also i have simple docker image https://github.com/mattes/rotating-proxy .

This image organize http tor proxy.

I want to configure dynamic port mapping to allow service scale tasks on one EC2 instance. But when i configure dynamic port mapping and try to run task (not even service, only task) instance doesn't respond.
I already tried to create service with application load balancer but this didn't help. So i'm sure the problem is related to task configuration.

But when i deploy task to cluster it writes "RUNNING" in it's status.

Here's task's definition JSON.

```
{
  "ipcMode": null,
  "executionRoleArn": null,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "dnsSearchDomains": null,
      "logConfiguration": null,
      "entryPoint": null,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 0,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 5566
        }
      ],
      "command": null,
      "linuxParameters": null,
      "cpu": 0,
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "tors",
          "value": "5"
        }
      ],
      "ulimits": null,
      "dnsServers": null,
      "mountPoints": [],
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "secrets": null,
      "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
      "memory": 200,
      "memoryReservation": null,
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "image": "305605212.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/rotating-proxy",
      "disableNetworking": null,
      "interactive": null,
      "healthCheck": null,
      "essential": true,
      "links": null,
      "hostname": null,
      "extraHosts": null,
      "pseudoTerminal": null,
      "user": null,
      "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
      "dockerLabels": null,
      "systemControls": null,
      "privileged": null,
      "name": "container"
    }
  ],
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "memory": null,
  "taskRoleArn": null,
  "compatibilities": [
    "EC2"
  ],
  "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:3056095212:task-definition/test-task:4",
  "family": "test-task",
  "requiresAttributes": [
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
    }
  ],
  "pidMode": null,
  "requiresCompatibilities": [
    "EC2"
  ],
  "networkMode": null,
  "cpu": null,
  "revision": 4,
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "volumes": []
}
```

Comment: Can you post the ecs-logs errors or event logs in case of service ?

Comment: There is nothing about it.
'service registered 1 targets in target-group'
service has started 1 tasks'.

Comment: from load balancer i get '504 Gateway Time-out'